# Lower bound for Zeta function on vertical lines

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I was wondering if it was known whether there was some $ \frac{1}{2}<a<1$ and a $c>0$ such that $|\zeta (a+it)| \geq c$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$? That is, does anyone know of any literature proving the existence/nonexistence of a vertical line in the critical strip with $\zeta (s)$ bounded below by a constant?

I couldn't find anything online, but I could be looking in the wrong places or this could be completely trivial and I just don't know it. Either way, I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: pretty confident there are no such results. There are articles about zero-free regions, but these always have curved edges.

Comment: Interesting, I noticed that when I was reading some results on this kind of thing, that was actually kind of why I asked.

Comment: If you can do it for one $a$ then why not for many $a$, dense in $(1/2,1)$ ? That would make us very close to proving the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Answering my own question: there is no such $a$ or $c$. For any $a$ in the given range, $\left\{ \zeta (a+it): t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Cf Voronin's "universality theorem".

Comment: @paulgarrett Do you know what makes a Dirichlet series special for being universal in some strip ? The Euler product and the analytic continuation ?

Comment: @user1952009, I would not claim to understand the argument... but so far as I do understand, it does use (of course) analytic continuation and Euler product, and features of the sequence of primes. Thus (some people whose names I've stupidly forgotten) have further proven universality for Dirichlet L-functions, and also some simultaneous universality results. But I think not for cuspidal L-functions, for example, because the proofs make very strong use of the elementariness of coefficients "1" attached to primes, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett In [Titchmarsh](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh%20E.C.%20The%20theory%20of%20the%20Riemann%20zeta-function%20(2ed.,%20Oxford,%201986)(T)(418s)_MCsf_.pdf) p.300 of the pdf it seems relying mostly on $\sum_p p^{-s}e^{i \theta_p}$ approximated by $\sum_p p^{-s-it}$ for the correct $t$, using a [theorem of Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem) and that $\{\ln p\}_p$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ linearly independent set.

Comment: @user1952009, ah, yes, I vaguely remember this aspect, and it seemed to me, superficially, that to make the obviously analogous argument succeed for cuspforms would require sharp estimates on size of Hecke eigenvalues, and such.

Comment: Yes I'm sure we need many information on the coefficients for obtaining the universality. For $Re(s) > 1$ it is easy to approximate $F(s) = \sum_p p^{-s}e^{i \theta_p}$  by $P(s+it) = \sum_p p^{-s-it}$ and to choose $\theta_p$ and $s$ for approximating some given sequence of derivatives $G^{(k)}(s_0)$. But how to extend this to $Re(s) \in  (1/2,1)$ ? If we assume the RH it is easier : since a bound for $F(s)-P(s+it)$ on a disk $Re(s) > 1$ extends to a bound on a larger disk where $F(s)-P(s+it)$ is analytic.